# WSL2: Launching VSCode from the command line using a *.code-workspace file

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-code, command-line, wsl-2

I have Windows 10 + WSL2 with the latest version of VSCode. I also have a simple .code-workspace file which I can double-click (from within the windows file-explorer) and launch VSCode in a way that it pops-up already attached to a specific docker-container that is up-and-running.

This works great with double-clicking on the .code-workspace file:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "uri": "vscode-remote://attached-container+7b2...27d/workspace/foobar"
        }
    ],
    "remoteAuthority": "attached-container+7b2...27d",
    "settings": {}
}
```

Apart from double-clicking I can also invoke VSCode from Windows command-line (dos) and this works ok too:

```
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\path\to\foobar.code-workspace"
```

However when I try to open the workspace from within WSL2:

```
  code ./foobar.code-workspace
```

Even though VSCode pops-up the workspace doesn't open properly. What should I do to make the WSL2 (bash) command-line work the same way as in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And to answer my own question:

```
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe"   ./foobar.code-workspace
```

Strangely enough this does the trick.

To make the script a bit more dynamic I guess one could write something like:

```
  "$(which code | xargs -0 dirname | xargs -0 dirname)/Code.exe"  ./foobar.code-workspace
```

Hope this helps some folks out there save a few hours worth of time.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day wsl is installed on top of a windows environment you could also a .bat or .ps1 file and adds the commands they require without the need for the workspace.
For example I have my script like this:
wsl (cd ~/Projects; code ./test; command3; command4)
exit
inside the parentheses put all the commands you need and exit closes the terminal